# Method accepts list of different objects in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

Is it possible to do this in Java:

- pass a parameter to a method which will accept list of different types
- as well as use that Class type inside the method ?

```
public class Test {
  public boolean testing(List<ClassType> testObjs) {
    int vals = 0;
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(testObjs)) {
      vals += testObjs.stream()
                      .map(ClassType::getTestType)
                      .filter(isTestobj::isTest)
                      .count();
                }
     do_processing_with_vals
     return boolean_value;
  }
}
```

There are 3 different classes which have method `getTestType` but unfortunately they are in different libraries and do not share a common parent class/Interface. I have to call a method (eg `testing`) which could take a list of either of these 3 class objects and do some processing with it. I do not want 3 different methods with only the difference being the class of the object that is passed (eg. `ClassType`).

When I use `Object` in place of `ClassType`, it throws error saying `cannot resolve method getTestType`.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type), a feature supported in languages like Typescript, Ceylon, and Scala 3. Unfortunately, Java does not have this feature. Three methods is probably the way to go. You could wrap it in something like the visitor pattern, but that's still going to come down to writing three different methods, since there's no interface in common.

Comment: A way to go would be to use `typeof` and cast in combination with throwing an exception if an unknown type is found.

Comment: If you have 3 unrelated classes that has a a method with the same name then it’s a coincidence and nothing you should build any logic around (the coincidence). So create 3 different test methods that each takes a list of the respective type

Answer (score 0):

Since the methods don't share a common interface (which is the best solution), the cleanest option may be to pass an appropriate Function or Predicate:

```java
public boolean <T> testing(List<T> testObjs, Predicate<? super T> isTest) {
  vals += testObjs.stream().filter(isTest).count();
}

...
testing(someObjs, ObjType::isTest);
```